# facing problem in filtering the data a summing the visible values

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub add_number()
    Dim a As Currency
    Dim i As Integer
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    a = 0
    For i = lastrow To Range("g4").Offset(1, 0) Step by - 1
     a = a + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Cells(h1).Value = a
   End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include a [mcve].  Just posting a title and code is not sufficient.  There is no where in the code where you filter, so is the data already filtered?  Please use [edit] to add an clarifications.

Comment: "facing problem" is no use to us here.  What *specific* problem are you facing?

Comment: `Step by - 1` should by `Step -1`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Up Filtered Column

- In Excel, you could use the [`SUBTOTAL function`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subtotal-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939).
- In VBA, you could avoid a loop and just evaluate a formula or write a formula to the cell as illustrated in the following code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumFilteredColumn()
    
    Const dRow As Long = 1 ' worksheet row
    Const sCol As Long = 7 ' n-th column of the range (table)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Restrict to continue only if the auto filter is turned on.
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the data column range.
    Dim scrg As Range
    With ws.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(sCol)
        Set scrg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim dCol As Long: dCol = scrg.Column ' n-th column of the worksheet
    
    ' Write the sum (subtotal).
    With ws.Cells(dRow, dCol)
        ' Write the value.
        .Value = ws.Evaluate("SUBTOTAL(109," & scrg.Address & ")")
        ' Maybe writing a formula makes more sense.
        '.Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(109," & scrg.Address(, 0) & ")"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: AMAZING STRAIGHT TO THE POINT, MY PROBLEM HAVE BEEN SOLVED , YOUR RIGHT USING FORMULAS MAKES MORE SENSE , THANK YOU